# kill command SIGKILL vs SIGTERM

Tags: kill, signals, sigterm

there was a nice write up somewhere on here about...

not using `kill-9` all the time which is SIGKILL and explained the reasons for doing so, and then went on to explain an order in which one should proceed from least aggressive `SIGTERM` ending up eventually at `SIGKILL` or rebooting.

**can someone post a link to that for me?  i cannot find it**

using `kill -l` to do a listing I receive as output on the terminal

*this is kill dash lowecase L, and NOT dash numeral one*

```
HUP   INT    QUIT     ILL      TRAP     ABRT     BUS      FPE      KILL   USR1
SEGV  USR2   PIPE     ALRM     TERM     STKFLT   CHLD     CONT     STOP   TSTP
TTIN  TTOU   URG      XCPU     XFSZ     VTALRM   PROF     WINCH    POLL   PWR
SYS   RTMIN  RTMIN+1  RTMIN+2  RTMIN+3  RTMAX-3  RTMAX-2  RTMAX-1  RTMAX
```

*I spaced out the above for readability.  This is from SLES 11.4 x86-64*

Am I correct in assuming the order of which these signal names are printed from `kill -l` correspond to the number you provide the `kill` command, such that if I wanted the bad *KILL* I would do `kill -9` and if I wanted the better choice of TERM that would be `kill -15` ?

- Is this the only way to find out these numbers on a given system?
- Is there a better more universal way of verifying what signals are available on a given linux system {RHEL, SuSE, debian, ... some stripped down version of linux from *i don't know where* used on some piece of hardware}?
- If I write code, where & how should one check something system level like this before assuming a signal is: first available, and then that `kill -number` corresponds to a specific signal?
- is there a good source for learning about all these types of signals, and what should be expected to always be available, for a typical *Linux* operating sytem?

Comment: start with `info kill` and `man bash` then /SIGTERM

Comment: I believe you can send any signal number that Linux kernel support. http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html 
  http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html As long as you have the right credential.